# Julia REPL: Mac shortcut to open in editor?

Tags: macos, julia, read-eval-print-loop

Julia 1.9 includes the ability to edit the current input in an editor. Per the [1.9 Release Notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-1.9/NEWS.md):

> Alt-e now opens the current input in an editor. The content (if modified) will be executed upon exiting the editor (#33759).

What is the equivalent shortcut on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> The Julia REPL makes great use of key bindings. Several control-key bindings were already introduced above (^D to exit, ^R and ^S for searching), but there are many more. In addition to the control-key, there are also meta-key bindings. These vary more by platform, but most terminals default to using alt- or option- held down with a key to send the meta-key (or can be configured to do so), or pressing Esc and then the key.

"meta key" is a concept familiar to Unix developers. On macs try "pressing and releasing `Esc`" followed by `e`